# Thin behind Nginx "no live upstreams while connecting to upstream"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, thin

I am getting this error in maybe one out of 50-100 requests.  I am running 10 Thin instances behind nginx and I don't think that my load is high enough to max out the usage in all 10 instances.. and I would expect nginx to wait even if all instances were busy (maybe not??).  Has anyone else seen this before?  I am trying to figure out a good way to debug it.

Here is my setup:
CentOS 5.5 on Rackspace Cloud Servers 2GB instance
nginx 0.7.67
Thin 1.2.7
Rails 3RC
Ruby 1.9.2rc2

Nginx and 10 Thin instances are running on the same server.

Comment: I don't have helpful advice for debugging it, but I vaguely remember running into this when I was running Thin. I solved it by running HAProxy between nginx and Thin; it implements request queues and can display a friendly "overloaded" page when it can't find a backend to serve a request.

Comment: after looking at my error logs this always occurs right after:

"upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream".  

There are a series of 10 errors like this.  I guess it must be retrying on every thin instance, and the next request that comes through (from a different user) always results in no live upstreams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

caches_action plus a redirect_to inside the action was causing this.  It appears that it was writing to the cache (or possibly reading from) and then redirecting which caused the connection to close prematurely.  I was able to get around the issue by using the if condition in caches_action to detect whether the redirect was going to occur.  If I detected that it was going to occur, I returned false in x.cacheable?

**my_controller.rb**

```
caches_action :show, :if => Proc.new { |x| x.cacheable? }
```

**action_controller.rb**

```
def cacheable?
  params[:id]>1000 ? true : false
end
```

Basically, I needed to redirect_to another controller if params[:id]<1000, so the cacheable? def checks this and tells caches_action not to cache in this particular situation.